# SQL Server "Login failed for user " Error During Specific Time Frame from .NET Console Application

Tags: .net, sql-server, authentication

We have a scheduled task on a `Windows Server 2012R2` machine which launches a custom built .NET application starting at 8AM each day and running once every hour.  The application communicates with a `SQL Server 2012` Database Server (different machine) via Entity Framework to fetch some data and do different things locally.  This configuration has worked without incident.

Recently, we `updated the application` to make an additional call to the database, only this time using `ADO.NET` and a `Stored Procedure`.  This works **MOST of the time**.

We've noticed during the hours of 9PM and 4AM we are receiving "Login failed for user" exceptions -  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)`.  I see these in logging done by the .NET application and also in the Windows Event Log on the Database server.

Both Entity Framework and the ADO.NET calls are using the same connection string which used SQL authentication.  I've verified this with some additional logging.  Also, manually connecting to SQL Server via SSMS using the credentials from the connection string works without error.  We also see the application running, connecting, and processing data without error for most of the day (again, verified by logging).  Based on all of this, I have come to the conclusion that this is not actually a username/password authentication issue but rather something on the SQL Server side happening during this time that is preventing login.

My first guess was that a database backup might be locking the DB in some way or putting it in single user mode.  Looking at the DB maintenance plan, I see that the DB is operating in Full recovery mode, performing one full backup daily at 12AM, differential backups every hour and T-log backups every 15 minutes.  These errors are consistently happening in-between backups so I don't think backups are the issue.

One interesting thing I see on the Database server.  In the Windows Event Log for the "Login failed for user" error event, if I look at the binary data in the event, it shows `HDB02.master`.  `DB02` is the database server name.  I'm not sure if the "H" or reference to the master DB in this context is indicative of the problem or something else.

Lastly, I don't see any additional logging of events on the sql server or the application server that offer any more clues into why this is happening.  I've scoured our source control for any code changes that may be contributing to this but nothing stands out.

Any additional suggestions on things I can look into would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Up until now this has exclusively happened only from the console application but just this afternoon it was triggered when we published an ASP.NET application that uses the same database, but a different SQL user.  Both applications are C# applications.

Comment: Did you look you search MSDN for that exception?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913765

Comment: That article is referring to a different exception (SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find prepared statement with handle 1.).  Sql Exception 0x80131904 appears to be a generic error that occurs for numerous different exceptions.

Comment: Check the SQL Server Logs too, to see if there's additional state noted for the exception. i.e. SQL Mgmt Studio > Server > Management > SQL Server Logs. Login Failed will normally give you a reason, error number, severity and state.

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to capture any events that seem relevant. Perhaps there'll be something there you can see that shows a difference between the two types of connections being made or anything else weird going on during the time where the connection fails.

Comment: Checked the logs, it is reporting Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.  State 8 indicates a password mismatch, which I know is incorrect.

Comment: I'm suspecting some possible corruption with the user so I've dropped it and recreated it.  We'll see if that takes care of the problem.

Comment: Dropping and recreating the user did not resolve the issue.  Hoping someone on SO has seen this before and can help.